# Change time from various time zones to EST

Tags: java, datetime

I have a list of strings indicating times in various time zones (e.g., "Fri, 26 Oct 2012 03:08:01 **+/-00XX**"). How to convert them all, for instance, to EST (or actually any single timezone)?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) them all to `Date` instances using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), create another instance of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and set the timezone you want and use [`format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) to format all parsed instances to required timezone

Comment: @Mr.Zeiss This answer is correct. Search StackOverflow for words like "java date parse" (format, etc.) to find many specific code examples. Tip: You'll do yourself a big favor if you include the search word "[joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)".